# Nested State problems

Tags: angular-ui-router, jhipster

I'm trying to insert a nested state under "home" (main directory) without success. I've read the Nested States documentation on agularjs.

Here is my main.html :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div ng-include="'scripts/app/main/leftmenu.html'"></div>
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">
        <!-- Page wrapper -->
        <div ng-include="'scripts/app/main/topnav.html'"></div>
        <!-- Main view  -->
        <div ui-view="mainview"></div>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <div ng-include="'scripts/app/main/footer.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Right Sidebar -->
    <div ng-include="'scripts/app/main/rightsidebar.html'"></div>
</div>
```

My main.js :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('foremnetApp')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                parent: 'site',
                url: '/',
                data: {
                    authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
                },
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'scripts/app/main/main.html',
                        controller: 'MainController'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    mainTranslatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('main');
                        return $translate.refresh();
                    }]
                }
            })
    });
```

My dashboard1.js

```
angular.module('foremnetApp')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('dashboard1', {
                parent: 'home',
                url: '/dashboard1',
                data: {
                },
                views: {
                    'mainview': {
                        templateUrl: 'scripts/app/main/dashboard1/dashboard1.html',
                        controller: 'Dashboard1Controller'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    mainTranslatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('main');
                        return $translate.refresh();
                    }]
                }
            })
    });
```

When I try to go to "http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard1", I return to my default route... Also, I'd like to make the "home" state an abstract one (like "account").

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, I've made the "home" state (main) abstract and the nested state worked. Is it a constraint of JHipster or angular-ui-router? Anyway, I don't need more.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('foremnetApp')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                abstract: true,
                parent: 'site',
                data: {
                    authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
                },
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'scripts/app/main/main.html',
                        controller: 'MainController'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    mainTranslatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('main');
                        return $translate.refresh();
                    }]
                }
            })
    });
```